# How do you find $D_n'$ when $n$ is even and odd?

Tags: group-theory

I know the commutator is $\langle r^2 \rangle$ in general.

I have to show when $n=2m$, then $D_n'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m$. I have the answer for when $n$ is odd as follows:

When n is odd $\langle r^2\rangle= \langle r\rangle$. So then since $|r|=n$ we get $D_n' = \langle r \rangle $ and this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Edit: When $n$ is even, $n=2m$, then $\langle r^2 \rangle$ is the commutator subgroup of $D_n$. $|r^2|=|r|/(|r|, 2) = n/(n, 2) = n/2 = m$. Then $D_n'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m$, yes?

Comment: what is $D_n'$?

Comment: @ZelosMalum $D_n' = [D_n, D_n]$

Comment: The question contains a typo. We have $n=2m$ , so $n$ cannot be odd. You mean "$m$ is odd".

Comment: @Peter I think you have misunderstood. I have to prove $D_n'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ when $n=2m$. When $n$ is odd, I have shown that in that case $D_n'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. I hope the problem is clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, $n=2m$. The element $r$ has order $n$, so the element $r^2$ has order $m$. Therefore the subgroup $\langle r^2\rangle$ has order $m$, so $\langle r^2\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_m$

Comment: I replaced $<$  $>$ by $\langle$ and $\rangle$, hope you don't mind!

Comment: No, I do not. :)